# how to reference data from json in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a json file with IPs in it. It's structured like the example below. I'm using jsondecode in terraform to ingest the file and i'm hoping to use the values in it. I'm able to use the "US" and "ALL" values without issue. The problem i have is when i try to reference the values under region. Please see below:

````json
    {
       "US": [
            "30.30.30.85",
            "30.30.30.86"
        ],
        "All": [
            "30.30.30.85",
            "30.30.30.86",
            "40.40.40.40",
            "40.40.40.41",
            "50.50.50.33",
            "50.50.50.34",
            "60.60.60.61",
            "60.60.60.62"
        ],
        "Regions": [
            {
                "US_Central": [
                    "40.40.40.40",
                    "40.40.40.41"
                ]
            },
            {
                "US_Southeast": [
                    "50.50.50.33",
                    "50.50.50.34"
                ]
            },
            {
                "UK": [
                    "60.60.60.61",
                    "60.60.60.62"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }


```hcl
locals {
  ip_list           = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/../ip_list.json"))
}
````

The ips variable fails with various errors depending on how i try to call it. Here are the ways i've tried so far:

```
ips               = local.ip_list.Regions[US_Central].value
ips               = local.ip_list.Regions.US_Central
ips               = local.ip_list.Regions[*].US_Central
```

Does anyone know what the proper way to reference these values is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `"Regions"` key is a list (denoted with `[`), you can fetch the first element of the list by using an index, e.g:

```
ips = local.ip_list.Regions[0].US_Central
```

Testing with `terraform console` gives:

```
> local.ips
[
  "40.40.40.40",
  "40.40.40.41",
]
```

However, if you want to fetch all the values for all the different keys (i.e., `US_Central`, `US_Southeast`, and `UK`), the code would have to be adjusted.

EDIT: I am most probably not doing this in the most elegant way, but here is how you can get all the values of IPs in one list:

```
ip_lists = values(merge(flatten([
    for i, region in local.ip_list.Regions : [
      for r, cidrs in region : {
        "${i}.cidr_block" = cidrs
      }
    ]
  ])...))
```

This will return a list of lists with CIDRs in all regions, and then the only thing left is to `flatten` it again:

```
flattened_list_of_ips = flatten(local.ip_lists)
```

which returns:

```
> flatten(local.ip_lists)
[
  "40.40.40.40",
  "40.40.40.41",
  "50.50.50.33",
  "50.50.50.34",
  "60.60.60.61",
  "60.60.60.62",
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That does seem to work, if I want to reference the next element in the list i use local.ip_list.Regions[1].US_Southeast, etc.. I tried using local.ip_list.Regions[US_Southeast].US_Southeast but that didn't work. Will have to keep that in mind if we ever update the regions list contained in the json. Thank you again sir!

Comment: Please take a look at this as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow/86979#86979.